# Multivariable Differentiability Definition Question about necessary condition

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples

My professor provided the following definition for multivariate differentiation:

**Definition:** For a function $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$, to be differentiable there must be a linear transformation $F$, and a function $g$, both dependent on $x$ such that $$f(x+h)-f(x)=F(h)+g(h)$$ where $$\lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{g(h)}{|h|} = 0.$$

> Why do we require $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{g(h)}{|h|}=0$ rather than simply $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0} g(h)=0$?

I've been trying to come up with an example that illustrates that $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{g(h)}{|h|}=0$ is necessary but cannot seem to think of anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the requirement were just $\lim_{h \to 0} g(h) = 0$, we could just take $F = 0$ (provided that $f$ is continuous at $x$). It helps to think about how the multivariable definition is equivalent to the standard definition from single variable calculus in the case where $m=n=1$.

Comment: We want the error term $g(h)$ to vanish “faster” than $h$, i.e., for it to be $o(h)$. Otherwise, you’ve only stated a condition for continuity as littleO said.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thank you both.